# One Point Compactification of $\mathbf{R}^n-\{0\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I wanted to know the one point compactification of $\mathbf{R}^n-\{0\}$. The actual problem asks to show that $S^n/\{p,q\} \simeq S^n \vee S^1$, where $p,q$ are two distinct points of $S^n$. I know that $S^n-\{p,q\}$ is homeomorphic to the one point compactification of  $\mathbf{R}^n-\{0\}$. So, knowing the result might help to solve the problem. Intuition from $\mathbf{R}-\{0\}$ is not helping much as that is $S^1\vee S^1$ and I couldn't work out for even $n=2$. Please help.

Comment: In general, the way to make a one-point compactification is to identify the limits of all sequences that you really want to converge.  In this case, it would be adding a point at infinity and identifying it with $0$.  If you think about the sphere $S^n$ and stereographic projection, this would correspond to identifying the north and south poles.

Comment: Ok, is it a known space? My guess would be something involved with wedge product.

Comment: Perhaps the example on page 11 on [Hatcher's Algebraic Topology](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I am not really comfortable with CW-Cells. Is there a solution with precise maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By stereographic projection, you can turn $\Bbb R^n-\{0\}$ into $S^n-\{N,S\}$. You want to make this compact by adding a single point. We wish to add $N$ to fix problems near the north pole and $S$ for problems near the south pole. So to solve both problems at once, we "pinch" $N$ and $S$ together and then only add a single point...

Comment: I got the idea, so what would be the final space?

Comment: @PSG A sphere with the north and south poles identified. This is homotopy equivalent to the sphere with a circle attached at a point.

Comment: For $S^1$ , I can see that if we pinch the $N$ and $S$ together we get $S^1\vee S^1$, it's difficult to see in higher dimension , maybe you can give a closed form of the space. Is it $S^n\vee S^1$?

Comment: Draw a line from N to S through the “hole” in the sphere. (Contracting the line gives you pinching, but now we want the line to be there.) Now move N along the sphere over to S, and see that the line becomes a circle.